# Getting a class' constant pool programmatically

Tags: java

Lets say I have class Foo:

```
public class Foo {
    // ...
}
```

I want to get its constant pool as a byte array from another class. i.e:

```
public class Bar {
    void butts() {
        byte[] fooConstantPool = Foo.class.getConstantPool();
        // ...
    }
}
```

`Class#getConstantPool` is not part of the standard API. Is there any consistent way I can get another class' constant pool?

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387415/class-getconstantpool

Comment: Unfortunately, as mentioned by the answer on the thread you linked, that method can't be accessed by any code, nor is it a public API. I'd quite like to stick to the standard Java API, if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it as `sun.reflect.ConstantPool` object via reflection like this:

```
import sun.reflect.ConstantPool;
public class Bar {
    private static final Method getConstantPool;

    static {
        try {
            getConstantPool = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getConstantPool");
            getConstantPool.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    void butts() {
        ConstantPool constantPool = (ConstantPool) getConstantPool.invoke(Foo.class);
        // ...
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure how to get it as byte array. You can try to serialize it :)

Comment: Unfortunately the interface of ConstantPool just calls native methods, so it can't be serialized.

Comment: Yes, you are right. What is the purpose of getting constant pool of a class? May be there is another way to achieve your goal? E.g. load .class file to byte array and use class loader after.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan your class loader to find the class's location on disk, then use a framework like BCEL to analyze it.

I have a website demonstrating this, but StackOverflow says I am not allowed to post links to it.